# Is there a java annotation for function ending the program? Get rid of "missing return statement"

Tags: java, annotations

I have the following code

```
public enum Animal {
    DOG,CAT;
    
    private void exitWithError(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        switch(this){
            case DOG:
                return "dog";
            case CAT:
                return "cat";
            default:
                //                missing return statement error
                exitWithError("unrecognized animal");

/*
                 workaround - don't like it
                 return null;
 */

/*               no error if exception thrown
                 throw new IllegalStateException("unrecognized animal");

 */

        }
    }
}
```

The above code results in a `missing return statement` error. I have some questions:

1. The `exitWithError` method should always finish program execution, right?
2. If the method always exits, is there any way I can inform the compiler about it so it doesn't throw the `missing return statement` at me?

The `return null` workaround seems to be bad code as if the code changed and this return statement would get executed it could cause problems.

Comment: A `toString()` method should never exit the program.

Comment: For this case, consider `public String toString() { return this.name().toLowerCase(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `toString()` method should never exit the program. More generally, *almost no* methods should attempt to exit the program.

Think about how surprising it would be for `System.out.println(EnumSet.allOf(Animal.class));` to cause the program to quit. (It wouldn't, now, but it might if you added another Animal and forgot to update `toString()`).

If you want to indicate something is wrong here, throw an exception (or an error), which allows callers to deal with it, if they are able to:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    switch(this){
        case DOG:
            return "dog";
        case CAT:
            return "cat";
    }
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

The `throw` is actually unreachable, but the compiler doesn't know this: the `throw` is necessary to convince the compiler that the method cannot complete normally (i.e. without returning a value or throwing).

Or, in Java 12+, the compiler will check for the completeness of a switch expression over an enum:

```
return switch (this) {
  DOG -> "dog";
  CAT -> "cat";
})
```

However, an alternative approach (usable pre-Java 12) would be to make the `toString()` a parameter of the constructor, so you never have to worry about having an `Animal` without a known `toString()`:

```
enum Animal {
  DOG("dog"), CAT("cat");

  private String string;

  Animal(String string) { this.string = string; }

  @Override public String toString() { return string; }
}
```

Comment: There is a final approach: `this.name().toLowerCase()`

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. The `exit()` in `toString()` was indeed an ugly example. I edited the question as it wrongly stated that a call to `System.exit()` would make the `missing return statement` error disappear. That is not the case as explained in: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446477/why-does-java-compiler-refuse-to-recognize-system-exit-as-a-procedure-terminat). Also java doesn't have a feature for marking methods that never end normally (also in the link).

Comment: @EMEM "Also java doesn't have a feature for marking methods that never end normally" not true: you give the method a return type. Non-void methods cannot complete normally, they have to return, throw, or provably not terminate (e.g. `int foo() { while (true) {} }`). [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7): "If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1)."